# call a scalar value function in stored procedure based on a condition

Tags: sql, t-sql

Hi am using a scalar function to compute some values and add it as a column while retriving the table.The query i was using is

```
Select * ,dbo.funcnme(@userid,itemid) as newvalue  from items
```

now i have a scenario in which i have to call a function based on a items value but i cant get it right.the query i tried is

```
select *,
    Case when items.Value=4 
        then dbo.funcnme(@userid,itemid) as newvalue 
        else dbo.newfuncnme(@userid,itemid)  
    as newvalue  from items
```

it shows

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'as'.

Whats wrong here.How can i do it please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm missing the `END` of the `CASE`, apart from that the alias should also be at the end:

```
select *,
    Case when items.Value=4 
        then dbo.funcnme(@userid,itemid) 
        else dbo.newfuncnme(@userid,itemid)  
    END as newvalue  
from items
```